# how to change the language of plastic SCM?

Tags: plasticscm

I installed plastic SCM cloud edition in my pc, but for accident the language installed was Spanish, I'm looking in the preferences but I dint found and I tried uninstall and re install but always when I open Plastic the language is Spanish

Answer (score 2):

You just need to find your client configuration file, typically in

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\plastic4\client.conf
```

and open it for edit. You'll find a  tag with the current language value ('es' in your local machine, as you mentioned that the UI is displayed in Spanish). Just change it to 'en' and the GUI language will be English.

Comment: I am using "Gluon". after changing config to "en", when I open Gluon app, the config continuously goes back to my local language(ko). any help??